# How to get PyGame window to respect Ubuntu's Screen Display Scale?

Tags: linux, pygame

On my laptop running Ubuntu I use a scaling factor of 200%.  On most apps this seems to work fine, but on a PyGame windowed window it does not - the window and its contents are not scaled.  Is there a relatively straight-forward way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the environment variable SDL_VIDEO_SCALE_METHOD to letterbox before running your PyGame program

To set the environment variable run the following command before running your PyGame program

export SDL_VIDEO_SCALE_METHOD=letterbox

you can set the environment variable directly when running your PyGame program using this

SDL_VIDEO_SCALE_METHOD=letterbox python my_pygame_program.py

Comment: Hello and thanks.  Neither SDL_VIDEO_SCALE_METHOD=letterbox python my_pygame_program.py nor adding:
"env": {
                "SDL_VIDEO_SCALE_METHOD": "letterbox"
              }
to the VS code launch.json changed how the window was scaled.

Comment: While setting the SDL_VIDEO_SCALE_METHOD environment variable should work for some systems, it appears that it may not work on all systems. Another approach to scaling PyGame windows on high DPI displays is to use the pygame.display.set_mode() method and pass in scaled dimensions manually.